# How to make this table of prime numbers display in reverse

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, numbers, reverse

I have created a table that displays all prime numbers from 2-1013 but it is displaying from the bottom right to the top left and I would like it to display from the top left to the bottom right. How would I achieve this?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML Public>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Prime Numbers</title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    </head>

    <body onload='CalcPrime()'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function CalcPrime() {
                var setIt = 0;
                var count = 0;
                var num = 3;
                var primeArray = new Array();
                primeArray.unshift(2)

                while (count < 169) {
                    setIt = 0;
                    var i = 2

                    while (i < num + 1) {
                        if (num % i == 0) {
                            setIt = setIt + 1;
                        }
                        i = i + 1
                    }
                    if (setIt < 2) {
                        primeArray.unshift(num);
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                    num = num + 1;
                }
                var a;
                document.write("<table cols='10' border='1'>");
                document.write("<tr><th colspan=10 border='1'>Prime Numbers 2-1013</th></tr>");
                for (var it = 0; it < 161; it = it + 10) {
                    document.write("<tr>");
                    for (var colm = 0; colm < 10; colm++) {
                        a = it + colm;
                        document.write("<td style='border:1px line;padding:10px;'>" + primeArray[a] + "</td>");
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you push your values onto the array instead of unshifting them, that will put them at the end of your array instead of the start. Which would do exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much that did exactly what I wanted and it was very efficient. I changed primeArray.unshift(num); to primeArray.push(num);

Answer (score 0):

This will get you close. Basically, instead if incrementing your indices, decrement them. Instead of starting with 0, start with the final number and go **down** to zero. In other words, reverse your loop.

```
for (var it = 161; it >= 0; it -= 10) {
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (var colm = 10; colm >= 0; colm--) {
        a = it + colm;
        document.write("<td style='border:1px line;padding:10px;'>" + primeArray[a] + "</td>");
    }
}
```

It's not perfect yet, but this will get you close for now. I'll edit after I tweak it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Before writing the table, reverse the `primeArray` variable by adding:

`primeArray = primeArray.reverse();`